# Is it possible to limit build queue for certain build configuration?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I am trying to work out an efficient setup to ensure that compiling and deploying builds takes priority over running tests. I have a single agent containing two build configurations:

- Build, deploy, high level test (5 minutes)
- Unit tests, integrations tests, smoke tests (15 minutes)

I have configured the triggers such that the build projects runs every time a commit occurs in VCS. What I would like to do is to queue up the test project to run as lower priority. However, if multiple commits are made in a short space of time (a few minutes), I do now want to queue up lots of test projects.

For example, this is what I would like to achieve:

- 12:00 commit
- 12:02 commit
- 12:08 commit

Build/deploy configuration kicked off at:

- 12:00 (eta 5 mins)
- 12:05 (eta 5 mins)
- 12:10 (eta 5 mins)

Test project kicked off at:

- 12:15 (eta 15 mins)

Where the test project runs just once with the latest deployed code. I do not want to queue up the test project 3 times.

Effectively, I only want to run the test project when the agent is idle and untested changes have been committed. Is this possible? if so, what is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For batching frequent commits you can use 'Quiet period mode' in VCS trigger settings, read about this [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-QuietPeriodSettings). To avoid build triggering if the configuration in queue now - disable checkbox 'Trigger a build on each check-in' in VCS trigger settings.

And to manage build queue priorities click on 'Build Queue' link and then on 'Configure Build Priorities'. At this place you can manage priority classes. Read more about this [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Ordering+Build+Queue#OrderingBuildQueue-ManagingBuildPriorities).

Note: You should be with System Administator role.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Quiet period mode would allow me to wait x minutes before kicking off the build, but it wouldn't actually prevent multiple builds from being added to the queue?

Comment: If you look at my example above, would a quiet period of 5 minutes not result in a test project being added at 12:07 and then again at 12:13. Due to the build priorities, the tests wouldn't run until after the third deploy (correct), but they would run twice on exactly the same deployment? A larger quiet period would result in the tests being run less frequently even when the agent is idle. Ideally I just want to be able to say 'when the build queue is empty, run the tests if there have been any untested changes'. I'm not sure if this is possible though.

Comment: If you disable 'Trigger a build on each check-in' and set big priority for non test configuration test build will stay in queue, stack changes and wait until agent will be idle.

Comment: Oh right, so if that option is disabled the test builds in the queue will be merged? I will test it out, but if so that will answer my question.